# An island, a boat, and a roulette

Tags: mathematics, probability

You are on an island where a volcano is going to erupt anytime soon, wiping out everything with it. The only way to leave the island is via boat, but the captain of the boat asks for £80 for the ride. You have only £70. On the island there's a casino with roulette. What do you do to maximize your chances of survival?

*(riddle taken from a Colin Bruce book)*

Comment: That boat captain is an a'hole. He'd let you DIE for the lack of a tenner?

Comment: Stay along with the captain, sure it saves your life. ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Place your bet where you have a 50% chance of winning (Red, Black, Odd, Even, etc.)

1. > Gamble £10. If you win £10, you're safe. If you lose, you still have £60 left.
2. > Gamble £20. If you win £20, you're safe. If you lose, you still have £40 left.
3. > Gamble £40. If you win £40, you're safe. If you lose, you're screwed.

So you have only a 1-in-8 chance of not making it off the island. Pretty good, given the circumstances.

Comment: @dr01 Thanks for the edit. I'm not really familiar with how a roulette works :-)

Comment: Relevant (and certainly long familiar to Rand, even if he doesn't know much about roulette specifically, since he's a mathematician): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox

Comment: Incidentally, on actual roulette wheels you have slightly less than a 50% chance of winning when you make such bets, because the wheel has an extra space (or sometimes multiple extra spaces) that don't count as red *or* black, as odd *or* even, etc. This doesn't change the choice of strategy, but it makes it slightly less likely to succeed.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Perhaps even more relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(betting_system)

Comment: @Gareth and GPR Yep, I've long heard about that "keep doubling the stakes, must eventually win" paradox. (It was also used to great and dramatic effect by Mat Cauthon - my namesake's gambling friend - in *The Gathering Storm*.) In this case, though, you've got nothing to lose in terms of money - if you don't get that extra cash, you're *dead*. Dovie'andi se tovya sagain, as Mat would say.